# CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports, windows-server-2003

I am using `Visual Studio 2003` ASP.Net . While browsing a page with crystal report, it is showing the below error.

error:

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.LoadSaveReportException: 
    Load report failed. 
        at .F(String    , EngineExceptionErrorID  ) at .B(String , Int32 ) 
        at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob) 
        at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String reportName)
```

Previously it was working. But currently it is moved to a windows server 2003 machine.

please help

Comment: had installed the Crystal report setup?

Comment: Thank u Alpesh,yes, I tried to create a new report and it was working. but old reports are not working.

Comment: i am thinking that you crystal reports version are different so if you want to use older one then please install the appropriate version.

Comment: In the Server, both visual studio 2003 and visual studio 2005 applications are there. VS 2005 is working properly.It is using CrystalReport 10.2.3600.0 and VS 2003 is with CrystalReport 9.1.5000.0.But I need both versions.

Comment: You can use The Same Version of Crystal Reports for the Both the Visual Studio But if you will go for Hire Version then you must need to change the Reference to Hire Versions.

Comment: To use the higher version, I changed the web.config file and html code behind the page with new version. but it gives error:The base class includes the field 'CrystalReportViewer1', but its type (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer) is not compatible with the type of control (CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalReportViewer).